# Need explanation on reverse scientific notation function in Lisp

Tags: scheme, lisp, explain, sicp, r5rs

Here's the function i have and understand to go from 1) your coefficient and 2) your exponent to then extract the number out of the scientific notation.

Example:

```
coefficient 7, 
exponent 3 

7 * 10^3 = 7000

(define (scientific coeffiecent exponent) (* coefficient (expt 10 exponent)))
```

Here's what im struggling with: The function to go the other way around, From 7000 to the coeffiecent and exponent used to get it into the scientific notation. I've got a working function through networking, but really struggle understanding it entirely.

```
(define (sci-exponent number)
  (floor (/ (log number) (log 10))))

(define (sci-coefficient number)
  (/ number (expt 10 (sci-exponent number))))
```

if anyone could help me understand, It'll be greatly appreciated! Thanks for reading either way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the body of `sci-exponent`, it takes the floor of log(number)/log(10). As you might remember from math class: log<sub>a</sub>(n1)/log<sub>a</sub>(n2) = log<sub>n2</sub>(n1). So what you're getting there is log<sub>10</sub>(number), the floor of which gives you the number of digits of `number` minus 1, which would be the exponent for the scientific notation.

The coefficient is then easily derived from the exponent. Since, as you wrote, `coeff * exp = number`, then `number / exp = coeff`, which is exactly what `sci-coefficient` is implementing.